# How to select the current month's birthdays using Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table of 30,000 names and birthdays. I need to pull the current month's birthdays out. Date format is 06/01/2020. Appreciate any help I can get.
Table name is `BIRTHDAYS`. I need to pull out all these 3 fields data for that person.

```
First Name     Last Name    Birth Date            
Steve           Johnson     06/24/1985     
Joe             Smith       06/05/2000      
Brenda          Cater       04/20/1970 
Cathy           Proctor     01/10/1972
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data.

Comment: Presumably you need to select the rows where the month part of the birth date is the same as the month part of the current month: MONTH(birthdate) = MONTH(TODAY) in one non-Oracle dialect of SQL.  You need to work out the equivalent in Oracle.

Comment: You wrote in your question: _Date format is 06/01/2020_ No it's not. Format is only used to display a DATE value.

Comment: In order to provide you with a relevant answer, it would help if you provide the following details. What is the name of the database table containing the birthdays? What is the name of the "birthday" column? What is the data-type of the "birthday" column? What data do you want to retrieve? Do you want just the name?

Comment: Is _First Name_ really the name of a column in your BIRTHDAYS table? And you still haven't provided the data-type for column _Birth Date_. Is it DATE?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT NAME,BIRTHDAY
FROM schema_name.table_name
WHERE to_char(BIRTHDAY,'mm') = to_char(sysdate, 'mm')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column is named `Birth Date` of type DATE in table `birthdays`:

```
select to_char("Birth Date",'MM') from birthdays;
```

Answer (score 0):

to_char will work, but here is another option:

```
select first_name, last_name, birth_date
from birthdays
where EXTRACT(MONTH from TO_DATE(birth_date,'MM/dd/YYYY')) = EXTRACT(MONTH from sysdate)
```